# loop through json array jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I'm trying to loop through this to get the 'name' values.  This is what I currently have, but it doesn't seem to be working, tried a few others from what was posted here but nothing seemed to work.

```
    $.get("/get_names", {campaign_id: $('select[name="id"]').val()}, 
                function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        alert(item);
                    });
                }
   );
```

Json being returned:

```
   [
           {
              "name":"age"
           },
           {
              "name":"asdf"
           },
           {
              "name":"drivername"
           },
           {
              "name":"drivers"
           },
           {
              "name":"firstname"
           },
           {
              "name":"gender"
           },
           {
              "name":"lastname"
           },
           {
              "name":"make"
           },
           {
              "name":"model"
           },
           {
              "name":"vehicles"
           },
           {
              "name":"year"
           }
        ]
```

I've tried using:

```
item.name
item[i].name
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: returns a single bracket, '['

Comment: that means it's not treating it as an array...

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You have to parse the string as JSON (`data[0] == "["` is an indication that `data` is actually a string, not an object):

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item);
});
```

Comment: that is that i wrote below :)

Comment: But doesn't this make the script async??

Answer (score 11):

you could also change from the `.get()` method to the `.getJSON()` method, jQuery will then parse the string returned as `data` to a javascript object and/or array that you can then reference like any other javascript object/array.

using your code above, if you changed `.get` to `.getJSON`, you should get an alert of `[object Object]` for each element in the array. If you changed the alert to `alert(item.name)` you will get the names.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think youre returning json object from server. just a string.

you need the dataType of the return object to be json